# Ubuntu 18.04.1 Failure to boot on Thinkpad X230

Tags: boot

It's as the Title says, Just downloaded the ISO for Ubuntu 18.04.1
transferred it to a USB stick and installed from there.
After install asks you to restart the machine and hard drive does a few accesses and then just hangs with a black screen.

Had the same Issue after installing Ubuntu 18.04 it ran fine and then allowing it to auto update.
Tried grub menu options repair etc.

I'm a bit miffed as I was hoping to move away from Windows 10. 
Should I just stick with 18.04 and disable all updates?

Comment: How far do you get? Do you see grub at all?
Have you tried any suggestions from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it ?

Comment: What brand/model system. If nvidia video Edmund L suggestion should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to boot with `acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Linux'` or `acpi=off` or `nomodeset` in kernel parametets? If it boots with the first two something is wrong with your ACPI tables.

Comment: neither of the first two ideas work, only adding `acpi=off` which wasn't required for Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04